# Difference between nutation and polar motion

Tags: terminology, rotational-kinematics, precession

If you add a mass to your spinning globe or just change the mass distribution does it increase nutation or polar motion? And How do I calculate nutation? For this I take earth as an example. from what I understand nutation and polar motion are 2 different motions. Nutation is the earths axis tilt changes for about 2°because of the moons gravity force,so it can change from 22°to 24°.and polar motion is when the degree of axis tilt is fixed. But the 2 points it passes the earth changes.For instance the tilt would be 23°.But instead of north pole and south pole,the axis passes through supposedly canada and somewhere south australia (exaggrated).in nutation the axis of rotation actually changes but in polar motion the axis of rotation is fixed,but the earth changes and drifts down. Now for instance can mass changes ever affect earth nutation? Resulting in tilt increasing more than 23°?